# retrieve sub-string starting at mid-point in bash script

Tags: bash

Using bash script, is there a simple method to extract a sub-string starting in the middle of a path to filename?

From research I found this http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html but it seems matching sub-strings starting at a mid-point is not possible.

I have a bash script for cataloguing contents of specific directories and sub-directories that are mirrored on different back-up drives.  Using dirname I can assign the path to a variable but I do not want the entire path.  Here is a sample of some of the paths I am likely to deal with:

```
/media/mediaLibrary/movies
/medis/BackUp-01/movies/any_directory
/mnt/BackUp-02/movies/any_directory/any_directory
```

I want the steps necessary to drop anything in front of movies.  The above samples would become:

```
movies
movies/any_directory
movies/any_directory/any_directory
```

Comment: +1 for better than average 1st post. Thanks for sample data and expected outputs. Keep using the `{}` edit tool to keep things readable. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all.  @ anubhava: posting the entire script is not necessary. I used your suggestion and figured out what I was doing wrong.  The script is now returning results as designed and expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure BASH way:

```
for s in '/media/mediaLibrary/movies' '/medis/BackUp-01/movies/any_directory' '/mnt/BackUp-02/movies/any_directory/any_directory'
do
   echo "${s/*movies/movies}"
done
movies
movies/any_directory
movies/any_directory/any_directory
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy input.  It works at the command line but not in my script.  Can you help?  script `path=dirname $file (\n)path=${path/*movies/movies}`. [back single quotes omitted (\n) signifies new line in script]  In my file all these are dumped out to, path is returned as empty.

Comment: If you post your script in the question I can sure assist you further.

Comment: @dwlamb: I am waiting for your script to to suggest you ways to fix it.

Comment: Also as you can see don't post code in comments which is very difficult to read. Edit your question and provide your code there.